# Center dynamic width div horizontally, within another dynamic div

Tags: html, css

A seemingly simple issue, but other solutions I found didn't quite work here.

Attempting to center '.grid-wrapper-inner' within '.grid-wrapper'

```
.grid-wrapper {
    background:grey;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:90%;
    padding:80px 0;
    text-align:center;
    }

.grid-wrapper-inner {
    background:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    }
```

I thought 'display:inline-block' (with 'text-align:center' on the parent) would achieve this, but have hit a brick wall

Best explained here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YrF9C/1

Essentially need to prevent grid-wrapper-inner from taking up 100% of its parent div so it can be centered.

I did get the green boxes (see link) centered by using inline-block on those, but orphaned boxes at the bottom were then centered, which isn't the desired effect.

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `width` to `.grid-wrapper-inner`. You can try set 90%, you will notice the difference.

Comment: I need `.grid-wrapper-inner` to have a dynamic width though (set by the total width of the collective floated divs within it)

Comment: You can get a similar behavior if you put `max-width: 90%` on `.grid-wrapper-inner`. It will be dynamic, but if the content was too wide, the max width will be 90% of `grid-wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

.You could do one of two things:

add a width to the inner wrapper

```
.grid-wrapper-inner {
background:yellow;
display:inline-block;
margin:0 auto;
width:80%;
text-align:left;
}
```

or you could add padding to .grid-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin:auto to center horizontally, but for that to work the inner div you're trying to center needs to have some sort of width specified.  Otherwise it just stretches and the auto margin is 0.  Technically this is centered too, but not what you want.

For example try adding width: 86% to .grid-wrapper-inner.

Alternatively if you don't want to set a width, you'll need to set an actual margin that's the same left and right, e.g. change  margin:0 auto; in  .grid-wrapper-inner to margin: 5% or margin: 50px.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `padding:80px 0;` change it to `padding:80px;`. You are setting the padding only for top and bottom but the left and right is 0 so the inner div is expanding up until the left & right border of the wrapper div. Its still centred both vertically and horizontally just padding is 0 on the left and on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Setting width to `.grid-wrapper-inner`, would solve your problem, but apparently you cannot or don't want to do it. Then, if you still want to make the layout adapt to screen size, perhaps you could think about using [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)?